# How can I make a sticky header like https://www.acorns.com/ with React js

Tags: reactjs

This is the component I am using.

CSS has been added..everything working just while scrolling the opacity need to be changed to 1 from 0.Need to change css class.Figured out this code but not working within the component.How to put it within the component??I am a newbie in react.

```
var componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
     if(//scroll position is top){
         class = 'bg-helper';
     } else {
         class = 'sticky';
     }
     this.setState({
        activeClass: class
     })
  });
}
```

Comment: You want to stick the header after some scroll position or it will always be sticked?

Answer (score 0):

You could either stick with a library for this problem (react-sticky) or you could check the scrollPosition with the topPosition of your sticky element.

```
const initialTop = myStickyElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;

window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  if (window.scrollY < initialTop) {
    this.setState({ activeClass: 'bg-helper' });
  } else {
    this.setState({ activeClass: 'sticky' });
  }
};
```

The problem is, that when the client viewport changes (flipping smartphone) this code doesn't work properly.

However, if you want to change to sticky when the height of the header element is scrolled by, you could just modify this line:

```
const initialTop = myStickyElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```